# Programmatically creating view pager in tab bar, but view pager content scrolls through the tabs

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin

As the title says, i've created a view pager with a tabbar.  I am using a NestedScrollView as the parent layout, with a CoordinatorLayout as the child.  The issue is that when i scroll up and down the page the contents scroll through the tab title.  I have tried using an AppBarLayout, but it doesn't allow scrolling, so i've had to remove it.  I was wondering if there is anything obvious that i am missing?  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here's a snippet of the code (in Kotlin):

```
    val scrollView = NestedScrollView(activity)
    scrollView.layoutParams = ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT)
    scrollView.isFillViewport = true

    val rootLayout = CoordinatorLayout(activity)
    rootLayout.layoutParams = rootLayout.setDimensions(CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT)

    val tabLayout = TabLayout(activity)
    tabLayout.tabMode = TabLayout.MODE_FIXED
    tabLayout.tabGravity = TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL
    rootLayout.addView(tabLayout)

    tabLayout.layoutParams = CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams(CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)
    tabLayout.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(activity, R.color.account_background))

    val viewPager = ViewPager(activity)
    viewPager.id = 11122

    viewPager.layoutParams = CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT).apply {
        behavior = AppBarLayout.ScrollingViewBehavior()
    }

    setupViewPager(viewPager, data[0])

    rootLayout.addView(viewPager)
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager)

    scrollView.addView(rootLayout)
    return scrollView
```

Here is what it looks like:

[image: Scrolling through the tab title]

Comment: What language is this?

Comment: Apologies for not mentioning it as part of the description, it's Kotlin.

Comment: I added the Kotlin tag. I am not yet familiar with the syntax. Please make sure that the code you provide is complete. In other words, anyone should be able to copy and paste it and still compile it as-is without any additional errors. See [mcve] for additional tips on posting code samples.